# If and how security-oriented CDNs protect from BFAs?

Tags: brute-force, cdn

I understand how some CDNs also suffice protection from DDoS attacks by distributing content serving via various machines instead just one machine so that distributed attacks on one machine become unfeasible.

If I am not mistaken, such CDNs can also help protect against brute force attacks and if so it might be good for me because I am currently having some trouble setting rate limiting due to some *shared hosting* AND *content management system* mismatches.

If and how security-oriented CDNs protect from BFAs?

Comment: @nobody funny, I am the one who asked that almost three years ago and I didn't recall that but my memory was totally refreshed in that context after that reference. Thank you !

Comment: And yes, it does ha ha.